# How to select the Pilz Motion Planner?

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i use MoveIt with ROS Melodic and Ubuntu 18.04.
At a first stage i install MoveIt with binary. But if i got it right, the Pilz Planner isn't a part of this installation.
So i build MoveIt from source without problems in another workspace (does this matter?).
But how can i select this planner? If i change the pipeline in my move_group.launch, i got an error:

> MoveGroup running was unable to load pilz_industrial_motion_planner::CommandPlanner

i downloaded the *pilz_industrial_motion_planner_planning_pipeline.launch.xml* into my launch directory. But i don't know what i have to do in addition to get thinks work.

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381019/how-to-select-the-pilz-motion-planner?/) by [anonymous74883](https://answers.ros.org/users/74883/anonymous74883/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is an apt package that contains the pilz motion planner. Install it with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-pilz-industrial-motion-planner
```

---

Originally posted by [pvl](https://answers.ros.org/users/74901/pvl/) with karma: 111 on 2021-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous74883](https://answers.ros.org/users/74883/anonymous74883/) on 2021-06-24**:
That makes life easier. I will try it. Thanks a lot!!

**Comment by [pvl](https://answers.ros.org/users/74901/pvl/) on 2021-06-24**:
You are welcome ;). Let me know if it works and if it does please accept the answer to let others know that it works.